# How can I remove an empty value that is generated when I use breaks = seq()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using a dataset that has some data about the number cases of a disease vs the year they occurred. The thing is that I don't have information for the year 1997, but I'm using:

```
scale_x_continuous("Year", 
               breaks = seq(1996, 2013))
```

To arrange in a bar plot (with geom_col) the years (x) vs the cases (y). However, because the 1997 doesn't even exist in my data frame, the fact that I'm using those breaks generates it, and I have a blank space in my plot.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Can you not create `breaks` with numbers that you want. `breaks = c(1996, 1998:2013)` ?

Comment: Thanks you! The 1997 label went away, but unfortunately I still have a blank space between two bars, 1996 and 1998. I'll check how to give a reproducible example and edit my post.

Comment: Convert the x_axis to factor then the space will went away!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(12345)
# Random sample data
data <- data.frame(
  year = c(1996, 1998:2013),
  data = runif(n = 17, min = 100, max = 10000)
)

data
#>    year      data
#> 1  1996 7236.9486
#> 2  1998 8770.1546
#> 3  1999 7633.7251
#> 4  2000 8872.6332
#> 5  2001 4619.1615
#> 6  2002 1747.0807
#> 7  2003 3318.4443
#> 8  2004 5141.3209
#> 9  2005 7304.2820
#> 10 2006 9898.3957
#> 11 2007  441.9008
#> 12 2008 1608.4976
#> 13 2009 7383.2810
#> 14 2010  111.2522
#> 15 2011 3972.9130
#> 16 2012 4678.6971
#> 17 2013 3942.6254

# Plot with continous scale - blank space on graph
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data, mapping = aes(x = year, y = data),
    stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous("Year", 
    breaks = c(1996, 1998:2013))
```

[image]

```r
# convert year to factor when plot - no more blank space
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data, mapping = aes(x = factor(year), y = data),
    stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete("Year")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Wow you are a genius, it worked! The only thing I had to change is geom_bar to geom_col. It was giving me this error: Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic. Thank you!